# Paypal sandbox 'Pending' multicurrency

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Im currently using PayPals rest api. When executing payment it is returning as 'Pending' and the reason its stating is 'Multi Currency'.

The reason behind this is because the default 'facilitators' account is set to US i need it to all be in GB. The problem is I can login to user-facilitators@email.co.uk's account on sandbox.paypal.co.uk. I'm entering the email and password (which is 100% correct) and It wont let me login to sandbox so I can change the currency preferences back to GBP.

Does anybody no why?

Comment: I had the same problem. See my answer here:
[Same problem answered][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28602362/2301894

Answer (score 2):

In order to log into a Sandbox Paypal account, you have to be logged into your [Paypal Developer Account](https://developer.paypal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

as the default 'facilitators' account is set to US and you want to change it to other country. but this edit is not possible in sandbox.

so an alternate solution is **to create an another sandbox account**  and **set it to business account**. **set your desired country** and then **currency will be your country currency**, automatically.

after doing this, use this business account for testing instead of that default 'facilitators' account.

like this you can create any number of business accounts for any country/currency.

hope this will help to you and understood.

Comment: This worked for me, don't forget to add your new credentials to the paypal functions file from the facilitator profile!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once we register on Paypal developer site, as default, Paypal will issue us two default test account, one is merchant account and another is user test account. All there are fine.

**But the problem is their default currency is US, and We can't change them.**

When your Magento store's base currency has been set others, like AU, this issue definitely will come out with following system log:

```
        [CURRENCYCODE] => AUD
        [PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
        [PENDINGREASON] => multicurrency
```

**Create another merchant account and set the same currency with your Magento store, it will be fixed.**

payment_paypal_express.log

```
2014-12-12T01:51:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [GetTransactionDetails] => Array
        (
            [TRANSACTIONID] => 15Y48062WM0910211
            [METHOD] => GetTransactionDetails
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => OneStepCheckout_SI_MagentoCE
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [RECEIVEREMAIL] => john.yin.au-facilitator@gmail.com
            [RECEIVERID] => VQ37QYGD3SFPW
            [EMAIL] => john.yin.au-buyer@gmail.com
            [PAYERID] => LXDH2RT89NRAS
            [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
            [COUNTRYCODE] => US
            [SHIPTONAME] => john h
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => 33
            [SHIPTOSTREET2] => esdfd re
            [SHIPTOCITY] => ddw
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => AL
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => AU
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => Australia
            [SHIPTOZIP] => 34343
            [ADDRESSOWNER] => PayPal
            [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
            [INVNUM] => 100000036
            [SALESTAX] => 0.00
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-12-12T01:51:34Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 2ef746f5f1a77
            [ACK] => Success
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 14077178
            [FIRSTNAME] => Test
            [LASTNAME] => Buyer
            [TRANSACTIONID] => 15Y48062WM0910211
            [TRANSACTIONTYPE] => cart
            [PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
            [ORDERTIME] => 2014-12-12T01:50:39Z
            [AMT] => 44.00
            [TAXAMT] => 0.00
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
            [CURRENCYCODE] => AUD
            [PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
            [PENDINGREASON] => multicurrency
            [REASONCODE] => None
            [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Eligible
            [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
            [L_NAME0] => color swatch te
            [L_NUMBER0] => ZP-D3241-WHITE-L
            [L_QTY0] => 1
            [L_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
            [L_SHIPPINGAMT0] => 0.00
            [L_HANDLINGAMT0] => 0.00
            [L_CURRENCYCODE0] => AUD
            [L_AMT0] => 44.00
        )

    [__pid] => 30696
)
```